# supported APIs test fails UWP

Tags: c++, api, dll, uwp

I have developed a UWP application in c ++ / CX and I just do a deployment test. The majority of pass tests but the supported APIs test does not pass. In my application I use a library C which is the libpq (postgresql).

Here is the error generated by the test (part because it is very long) :

> L’API RtlGetNtVersionNumbers présente dans ntdll.dll n’est pas prise en charge pour ce type d’application. MSVCRT.dll appelle cette API.
>
> L’API IsWow64Process présente dans api-ms-win-core-wow64-l1-1-0.dll n’est pas prise en charge pour ce type d’application. kernel32.dll appelle cette API.
>
> L’API Wow64DisableWow64FsRedirection présente dans api-ms-win-core-wow64-l1-1-0.dll n’est pas prise en charge pour ce type d’application. kernel32.dll appelle cette API.
> L’API Wow64RevertWow64FsRedirection présente dans api-ms-win-core-wow64-l1-1-0.dll n’est pas prise en charge pour ce type d’application. kernel32.dll appelle cette API.
>
> L’API IsProcessInJob présente dans api-ms-win-core-job-l1-1-0.dll n’est pas prise en charge pour ce type d’application. kernel32.dll appelle cette API.
>
> L’API ActivateActCtx présente dans api-ms-win-core-sidebyside-l1-1-0.dll n’est pas prise en charge pour ce type d’application. kernel32.dll appelle cette API.
>
> L’API AddRefActCtx présente dans api-ms-win-core-sidebyside-l1-1-0.dll n’est pas prise en charge pour ce type d’application. kernel32.dll appelle cette API.

Comment: You can't use those APIs in a UWP app.  There is no workaround other than not using them and removing/replacing the component that is calling them.  The other option is to be a full Win32 Desktop app but that will not let you distribute through the Windows Store (there have been hints that this is about to change - not sure).

Comment: Do you use postgresql for local or remote database?

Comment: Ok, thanks you @RichardCritten.
zett42 I use postgresql for a local database

Comment: if this app is for PC only (not targeting phone, xbox, etc.), take a look at the Desktop Bridge and see if it could help you get your app to the Store: https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/bridges/desktop